# Is this a valid proof for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So I think I found a valid proof of the following series and just wanted to make sure I wasn't assuming anything incorrectly.

Define the series to be $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}$$ where it summates from $1$ to $\infty$.

I need to prove that it is uniformly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$

My approach is suppose $f_{n}$(x) = $\frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}$

From here I take the absolute value and do the following

$\left|\frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}\right| \leq \left|\frac{x}{x^2n^2}\right| \leq$$\left|\frac{x^2}{x^2n^2}\right|= \left|\frac{1}{n^2}\right|=\frac{1}{n^2}$
which I then defined to be sequence $M_n$ because |$f_{n}$(x)| $\leq$ $M_n$

But from the Weierstrass M-test we know that if $\sum_{n} Mn$ converges then the series must be uniformly convergent.

Note that since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges than by the M test the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}$$ must converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

Am I missing anything or is this a valid proof?

Comment: You use $|x|\leqslant |x|^2$ which cannot be justified for all $x\in\mathbb R$... The proof seems correct for all $x\in(-\infty,-1]\cup[1,\infty)$ but you should inspect the interval $(-1,1)$ again... Actually, the series does not converge for some $x$ in this interval...

Comment: If it does not converge uniformly does that not mean it cannot be uniformly convergent on R? @frog

Comment: Indeed, it does not converge on $\mathbb R$ therefore it does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb R$. Every $f_n$ has a pole in $-\frac{1}{n}$ so the infinite series will have poles in $-\frac{1}{n}$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: But the question given says prove it is uniformly convergent on R.... I noticed I made some errors on the series let me fix them

Comment: Ok now it's a different story but the problem remains. Try to separate the cases $|x|<1$ and $|x|\geqslant 1$. The new series is indeed at least convergent on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: The first part of frog's first comment still applies after the edit. And you can't use $M_n = 1/n^2$, but there is a $c \in (1,2)$ such that $\lvert f_n(x)\rvert \leqslant 1/n^c$, so you can still use the $M$-test.

Comment: @DanielFischer I keep ending up with c = 1.5 (or 3/2),

I am considering the case where x not equal to zero and so

$\frac{n}{|x|}$ + (n^2)*|x| $\geq$ 2n^$\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: That's good. It's the best $c$ you can get, since $f_n(1/\sqrt{n}) = \frac{1}{2n^{3/2}}$ (of course any $c$ between $1$ and $1.5$ would also work).

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok so I ended up where you did but just out of curiosity why did you use x = $\frac{1}{\sqrt(n)}$?

Comment: @wastemanz When $x=1/\sqrt n$, $f_n(x)$ attains its maximum value.  And inasmuch as $||f||_\infty =\frac1{n^{3/2}}$, we are done proving UC.

Comment: @MarkViola ah right. So I can check this by obviously taking the derivative of $f_n$(x) and then equating that to zero correct?

Comment: @wastemanz Indeed you can.  And in doing so, will arrive at the "best" $c$, as outlined in Daniel's comments.

Comment: Because $$f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\cdot f_1(\sqrt{n}\,x)\,.$$ Then pick a point where $f_1$ is large. (Needn't be the maximum, it just needs the same order of magnitude to see what's going on.)

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help!

Comment: @DanielFischer Just to clean up my proof a bit. By using the Weierstrass M -test, we can clearly see that the maximum value of $f_n$(x) = $\frac{1}{2*n^($\frac{3}{2}$)}$. Thus, |$f_n$(x)|
 $\leq$ $M_n$. And since we know $M_n$ is convergent then the series must be uniformly convergent.